# Are browsers supposed to consider windows updated with javascript pseudo-protocol URL output as new locations?

Tags: javascript, navigation, standards, url-scheme

I was wondering about browser differences in handling "javascript:" URLs. (Note: I'm aware that the "javascript:" scheme rarely makes much sense to use outside of bookmarklets or odd situations where one is restricted to using A hrefs instead of handlers. This is more out of general curiosity.)

Consider the following:

```html
<h1>Initial state</h1>
<p><a href="javascript:'<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>New State</title></head><body><h1>Changed state</h1><button onclick=alert(window.location.href)>Report location</button></body></html>'">Click here</a></p>
```

(It's not working for me in the SO "Run code snippet" frame -- perhaps because of some restriction on the iframe meant to block XSS? -- but anyway, you can [try it as a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x1etu3j/).)

Chrome 78.0.3904.108 and Firefox 70.0.1 both replace the page (or iframe) with the value of a string expression.* (Safari 13.0.3 doesn't appear to do anything with the returned value of the string expression after execution; the page state remains the same.)

(Strangely, in Chrome, if you already have DevTools open when the change happens, you have to close and reopen DevTools to seen the new DOM in the element inspector.)

After the change of state, in FF, the "Report location" button in the code above reports a "javascript:..." `window.location.href`. Chrome, on the other hand, reports it's still at the old location. (Consistent with this, if the page is the top frame of the browser window, FF updates the URL in the addressbar to a "javascript:..." address, and Chrome keeps showing the initial address.)

Was it ever specified somewhere which way browsers are *supposed* to react to javascript pseudo-protocol URLs?

It doesn't appear to be presently specified by the short ["javascript: URLs" section of the WHATWG wiki](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/URL_schemes#javascript:_URLs), nor the [2010 IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-03) that the WHATWG wiki section says it obsoletes.

A pertinent portion of the IETF 2010 draft said:

> In typical implementations, when the user activates the hyperlink, the web browser will pass control to the doSomething() function, and render its result, if any, in place of the current document.
>
> Some semantics of this operation are out of scope of this document. For instance, in the example above, if the doSomething() function returns a string object, the implementation would lack clues, like an Internet media type, how to process it; it could treat it as a script, style sheet, HTML document, resource identifier, or other type of resource, as appropriate for the context.
>
> In order not to limit the applicability of this scheme for certain applications, this document just describes this operation in terms of an abstract model; it is expected that, where needed, other specifications define the semantics in more detail using this model.

Meanwhile, the entirety of the WHATWG wiki page section is:

> ## javascript: URLs
>
> ---
>
> javascript: URLs represent a JavaScript script.
>
> To **obtain a script** from a javascript: URL, run these steps:
>
> - Let *input* be the concatenation of URL's scheme data, followed by "?" and URL's query if URL's query is non-null, followed by "#" and URL's fragment if URL's fragment is non-null.
> - Set *input* to the result of [percent decoding](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-decode) *input*.
> - If *input* starts with a U+FEFF, remove a single occurrence from the start of *input*.
> - Return input.
>
> See also [The 'javascript' resource identifier scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme) which this wiki page obsoletes.

But that's all I found. Were expected behaviors (particularly regarding location) ever specified in more detail elsewhere by one of the standards bodies?

---

**Note: Firefox, but not Chrome, will also do the page replacement if given expressions that evaluate to numbers, booleans, functions, and objects. [A test](https://jsfiddle.net/5moh14va/) for the various expression types:*

```
<p><a href="javascript:'hello';">test string</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:3+3;">test number</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:true;">test boolean</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:function f(){console.log('n')};f;">test function</a></p>
<p><a href="javascript:var o={};o.toString=function oToString() {return 'return of the toString() method'};o;">test object</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is part of the ["navigate" algorithm in the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigate).

There are also various tests in [web-platform-tests](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt) around this, but as you found there are still interoperability bugs in browsers, and the spec and tests probably also have bugs. See [open issues](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22topic%3A+javascript%3A+URLs%22).

Comment: Could you expand the answer to state whether the FF way (window.location.href="javascript:...") or the Chrome way (window.location.href unchanged) is the correct behavior according to the ["navigate" algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigate) in the standard, or if it is left ambiguous even there? In an example, they say "Once evaluated, its return value (if it was a string) would replace that browsing context's active document, thus also changing the corresponding Window object." But that still leaves me unclear if window.location.href must be changed.